# Forcing symmetric solution to matrix equation

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

For a physics application, I need to find the solution $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$ to the matrix equation

$$ AX=B $$

where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, and $n \gg m$. Roughly speaking, $n = 2 \cdot 10^4$ and $m = 150$.

Partitioning the matrices into blocks,

$$ 
\begin{pmatrix}I_m & A_1 \\ 0 & A_2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}X_1 \\ X_2 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}B_1 \\ B_2 \end{pmatrix},
$$

where $A_2$, $X_1$, and $B_1$ are square. I am only interested in obtaining $X_1$, but it is necessary to solve for the entire $X$ in order to have a fully determined system. $X_1$ should be *symmetric*, and I am looking for a way to solve this equation in such a way the forces the symmetry of $X_1$.

Currently, I use an LAPACK routine which solves the system for each column of $X$, and the resulting $X_1$ is symmetric up to some precision, but I am having issues with numerical instability so I am hoping that knowing $X_1$ should be symmetric might add some extra condition to the system that improves the stability of the solution.

Is there a way to rewrite this expression in such a way that when I solve it $X_1$ is guaranteed to be exactly symmetric?

Comment: _X_ is an _N_ \* _M_ matrix, where depending on the calculation _N_ is about 20,000 and _M_ is about 150. _A_ is _N_ \* _N_, with the identity block in the top left being _M_ \* _M_, then _A1_ is _M_ \*( _N_-  _M_ ) and A2 is ( _N_ - _M_ )\*( _N_ - _M_ ). _X1_ and _B1_ are _M_ \* _M_, and _X2_ and _B2_ are ( _N_-  _M_ )\* _M_.

Comment: Discarding the symmetry constraint, we have $m n$ equations in $m n$ unknowns. With the symmetry constraint, the number of unknowns is reduced and the system becomes overdetermined.

Comment: What do you mean by "having issues with numerical instability"? If the issue is that $X_1$ is not exactly symmetric (but should be), you can always "symmetrize" your $X_1$ by setting $X_1:=\frac{1}{2}(X_1+X_1^T)$ which gives a symmetric $X_1$ even in finite precision.